# Scraping checkbox with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

This is the Table that I want to extract from. And the Element of Checkbox looks like this.

[image]

I was scraping data via using datagridtable.

```
string Header = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#gridComponent > div.k-grid-header > div > table > thead > tr")).Text;
        // Get rows strings
        foreach(string row in Header.Split('\r'))
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
        }
        string[] HeaderSplit = Header.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // create DataTable
        foreach (string c in HeaderSplit)
        {           
            dt.Columns.Add(c);
        }     

        var table = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#gridComponent"));

        //Get Row value
        foreach (var row in table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")))
        {
            //Configure Number of Col and row
            int cellIndex = 0;
            string[] arr = new string[11];

            //Get Cell Data
            foreach (var cell in row.FindElements(By.TagName("td")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cell); 
                //Number of Col Data Load
                    if (cellIndex <= 10)
                    {
                        arr[cellIndex] = cell.Text;
                    }
                    else
                        continue;    

                cellIndex++;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(arr);
        }
```

I could not be able to pick up checkbox cause it was not in a text form. What should I do to scrape all the data from checkbox in the website with True&False?

Comment: Have you tried `element.Selected`? https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/?topic=html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Selected.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can get it with `.getAttribute('checked')`

```
bool cbox = Convert.ToBoolean(row.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).getAttribute("checked"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Where should I place this code to mine to display that on a column that I want?